# Bing Maps behind elements

Tags: html, css, bing-maps

How do I send Bing Maps to the back of my web page? I have a header that should be always on top, but I can't figure out how to put it in the foreground of Bing Maps. As shown in the print screen (can be found [here](http://i41.tinypic.com/mr4ao8.jpg)), everything goes behind the header, except the map.

I already tried the z-index, but without any luck. Does someone has an idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for z-index to work properly, try explicitly setting the `position` attribute of the map and your top bar, as well as the `display` attribute.

Try this:

```
#top_bar {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  z-index:10;
}


#map {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  z-index:5;
}
```

You don't have to set any of the directional attributes for the position (like `top`, `left`, etc..) so it won't change it's actual position. Additionally here is a good read as to why: http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/css-how-to-use-the-z-index-property/